# Convertng CMD line arguments to numbers character by character

Tags: c, numbers, encode, letters

In my c program I have attempted to make arguments passed by the command line to be converted into numbers. In other words I want `'a'` to be equal to 1 and `'z'` to be equal to 26.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,num;
    for(i=1; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; ++j)
        {
            //printf(":%c", argv[i][j]);

            if (argv[i][j] >= 'A' && argv[i][j] <= 'Z')
            {
                num = argv[i][j] - 'A';
            }
            else if (argv[i][j] >= 'a' && argv[i][j] <= 'z')
            {
                num = argv[i][j] - 'a';
            }
            num = num + '0';
            printf("%d\n", num);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I run this command:

```
./encript a
```

I would expect my program to return a value of one but instead I get this:

```
48
```

Comment: You could probably make that all one line by changing the character to lower cause using a function from the #include<string.h> headerfile and then just subtracting 'a'.

Comment: "I want 'a' to be equal to 1" --> `num = argv[i][j] - 'a' + 1;`.    Delete `num = num + '0';`

Answer (score 1):

In your program, you do this addition:

```
num = num + '0';
printf("%d\n", num);
```

This will add 48 (ascii of 0) to the calculated number.

In addition, `'A'-'A'` equals **0** and not to **1**